# How can I run gparted over ssh?

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh, partition, sudo

I'm SSHing into my RPi, with X forwarding enabled. I'm trying to run gparted, but it seems to fail for me.

```
$ gksudo gparted
======================
libparted : 2.3
======================
The program 'gksudo' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)'.
  (Details: serial 229 error_code 10 request_code 130 minor_code 5)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

or

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo gparted
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

(gpartedbin:21437): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
```

If I run plain `gparted`, I get `Root privileges are required for running gparted.` in STDOUT, but I also get a dialogue box pop up. I've also run `gksudo leafpad`, which seems to work fine. How can I run gparted over ssh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have

```
ForwardX11 yes
```

in your local `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Now the problem is that when you `sudo`, you don't have the right credentials in `.Xauthority`. The `-E` option preserves your environment

so

```
$ sudo -E gparted
```

Comment: I use `~/.ssh/config` instead, but, yes, as per the question, it is already enabled. Also (as per the question), X forwarding works fine when testing with `leafpad`.

Comment: Note that running programs with `sudo -E` will make them use your home directory (e.g. `/home/pi`), so next time you run those programs as a regular user, they will fail to run because their config files are owned by `root`.

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck with this:

```
ssh -X pi@mypi
```

but this worked:

```
ssh -Y pi@mypi
```

Comment: This is because you don't have `ForwardX11Trusted=yes` in your `ssh_config`. It's better to set it, because not only untrusted X connection only works with `-Y`, but it also expires after 20 minutes or so, making you wonder why your GUI apps suddenly stop working.

Answer (score 0):

`gksudo` is [deprecated](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/133072/33476) now. Having said that, if you're issuing commands manually, you can just use `sudo` instead.

Set the following options in your `ssh_config`:

```
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

The first option alone will work, but keep in mind that untrusted X sessions expire after 20 minutes or so, making you wonder why your GUI apps suddenly stop working.

In order to provide access to the X display to the target user of `sudo` (typically `root`), you can copy your connection cookie from `/home/pi/.Xauthority` to `/root/.Xauthority` with

```
sudo xauth add $(xauth list | tail -1)
```

Avoid running programs with `sudo -E`, as doing so will make them use your home directory (e.g. `/home/pi`), so next time you run those programs as a regular user, they will fail to run because their config files are owned by root.