# GUI password prompt replacement for gksu won't work via SSH

Tags: raspbian, ssh, sudo

Since `gksu` has been [deprecated](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=245932), I'm using the following script which emulates it using `pkexec`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PKEXEC_USER="root"
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  key="$1"

  case $key in
    -u)
    PKEXEC_USER="$2"
    shift
    ;;
    -D|-description|-m|--message)
    shift # ignore unsupported options with params
    ;;
    -*)
    ;; # ignore unsupported options with no params
    *)
    break # no more options
    ;;
  esac
  shift
done

pkexec --user "$PKEXEC_USER" env DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" $@
```

This works great locally, and I was expecting it to work in the `ssh -Y` session as well (given that `DISPLAY`variable is set), but it doesn't:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gksu bash
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/bin/env' as the super user
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  ,,, (pi)
 2.  root
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): 1
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

Why does `pkexec` fail, and (less importantly) why isn't it opening a GUI password prompt? Is there any other option I could use, aside from `lxqt-sudo`, which would install 150 MB worth of Qt libraries that I don't use otherwise, and is supposedly just as insecure as the original `gksudo`.

Comment: Interesting question! You might improve yr chances of an answer posting this on U&L SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that a separate copy of `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` must be running in the background within the current session for `pkexec` to work. If I run it before `gksudo bash`, then my scrip works fine via SSH as well:

[image]

Note that `pkexec` will not share the `xauth` cookie for you by default: you need to either [configure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/203136/106927) it to do so by setting `org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui` option to `true`, or share the cookie manually before you run `pkexec`:

```
sudo xauth add $(xauth list $DISPLAY)
```